# How to search a string in JS file (multiple lines) in python?

Tags: python

How to search a string in JS file (multiple lines) in python?

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    for file_contents in f:
        if ('search_string_1' in file_contents) or ('search_string_2' in file_contents):
           print('match found!')
f.close()
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data to the question?

Comment: Nothing's obviously wrong here.  Is this not working, or are you looking for other ways to accomplish this?

Comment: You do not have to use `f.close()` - wrapping `open` in a with statement does that for you at the end.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh the search string isn't matching, could you provide some sample to search a string in a multi-line file